# Function derivatives

Tags: algorithm

I have some function,

```
int somefunction( //parameters here, let's say  int x) {
    return something  Let's say x*x+2*x+3 or does not matter
}
```

How do I find the derivative of this  function? If I have

```
int f(int x) {
    return sin(x);
}
```

after derivative it must return cos(x).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422594/derivatives-in-c-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can approximate the derivative by looking at the gradient over a small interval. Eg

```
const double DELTA=0.0001;
double dfbydx(int x) {
  return (f(x+DELTA) - f(x)) / DELTA;
}
```

Depending on where you're evaluating the function, you might get better results from `(f(x+DELTA) - f(x-DELTA)) / 2*DELTA` instead.

(I assume 'int' in your question was a typo. If they really are using integers you might have problems with precision this way.)

Comment: aaa  thanks Andy  then i should use float or double yes?it will be more correct

Comment: @davit yes, when you start looking at small ranges like this you'll need to use floats or doubles. Your original functions are not incorrect for some uses, but they are not precise enough to get derivatives from.

Comment: thanks  for example  if we want to write program which uses  Newtons method or something like this i want   to learn how implement derivatives in programming  because sometimes it is necessary find maximum of function open some interval or like this things

Answer (score 1):

You can get the numerical integral of mostly any function using one of many [numerical techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration) such as [Numerical ordinary Differential Equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_ordinary_differential_equations)

Look at: [Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627055/compute-a-derivative-using-discrete-methods)

But you can get the integration result as a function definition  with a library such as [Maple](http://www.maplesoft.com/), [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/), [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/), or [SymPy](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/)

Comment: I believe he is talking about a 'black box' function f (i.e. you don't know what it is). If you can evaluate f, can you evaluate the derivative of f at certain point, is the question then, I believe.